# Genearte a list of strings compound of letters from other list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of letters:

```
>>> alphabet = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
>>> letters = alphabet.lower().split()    
>>> letters
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

I want to generate a list of strings as follows:

```
a b c d ... z aa ab ac ... az ba bb bc bd ... zx zy zz ... aaa aab ... zzzzz
```

In other words, I would like to have a list of each word of length less or equal to five characters compound of that alhabet.

Do I have to write 5 loops or use recursion? What is the most pythonic way to achive it? What approaches do you suggest?

Comment: Use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as al
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lis = ["".join(p) for i in xrange(1,6) for p in product(al, repeat = i)]
```

Comment: What should I change if I want to each word of length less than 10 characters? Only xrange(1,6) --> xrange(1,10) ?

Comment: @bzxcv17 Yes, but make sure you've lots of memory and time before creating such huge list.26**10 ---> `141167095653376` items.

Comment: Can I do it dynamically and not by keeping in memory, but getting one by one in order?

Comment: @bzxcv17 yes you can use a simple for-loop to make it memory efficient but still `141167095653376` iterations are going to take some time.