# Python 2.7 - Split comma separated text file into smaller text files

Tags: python-2.7

I was (unsuccessfully) trying to figure out how to create a list of compound letters using loops. I am a beginner programmer, have been learning python for a few months. Fortunately, I later found a solution to this problem - [Genearte a list of strings compound of letters from other list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041484/genearte-a-list-of-strings-compound-of-letters-from-other-list-in-python) - see the first answer.

So I took that code and added a little to it for my needs. I randomized the list, turned the list into a comma separated file. This is the code:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
from itertools import product
import random

list = ["".join(p) for i in xrange(1,6) for p in product(al, repeat = i)]

random.shuffle(list)

joined = ",".join(list)

f = open("double_letter_generator_output.txt", 'w')

print >> f, joined
f.close()
```

What I need to do now is split that massive file `"double_letter_generator_output.txt"` into smaller files. Each file needs to consist of 200 'words'. So it will need to split into many files. The files of course do not exist yet and will need to be created by the program also. How can I do that?

Comment: The easy part is creating and writing to these files. `open("name..", "w")` automatically creates a file if it doesn't exist already. With some loops and counters, this is not a hard task. The hard part is going to be naming the files something that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, part way there :-) I did not know that files could actually be created with that code too! If the files are simply named "output1.txt", output2.txt", "output3.txt" and so on until the last file is created, that will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, but I'm not sure why you're splitting this into smaller files. I would normally do it all at once, but I'm assuming the file is too big to be stored in working memory, so I'm traversing one character at a time.

Let bigfile.txt contain

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

```
MAX_NUM_ELEMS = 2 #you'll want this to be 200
nameCounter = 1
numElemsCounter = 0
with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as bigfile:
    outputFile = open('output' + str(nameCounter) + '.txt', 'a')
    for letter in bigfile.read():
        if letter == ',':
            numElemsCounter += 1
        if numElemsCounter == MAX_NUM_ELEMS:
            numElemsCounter = 0
            outputFile.close()
            nameCounter += 1
            outputFile = open('output' + str(nameCounter) + '.txt', 'a')
        else:
            outputFile.write(letter);
    outputFile.close()
```

now output1.txt is `1,2`, output2.txt is `3,4`, output3.txt is `5,6`, etc.

```
$ cat output7.txt
13,14
```

This is a little sloppy, you should write a nice function to do it and format it the way you like!

FYI, if you want to write to a bunch of different files, there's no reason to write to one big file first. Write to the little files right off the bat.

This way, the last file might have fewer than MAX_NUM_ELEMS elements.

Comment: Thank You :-) That worked like a dream. I have not used the `with` command with my python study course yet, so I am going to read more about that online now to get a better understanding of it. My brain is that much better for seeing how you created this. Thanks again - Darren

Comment: @Darren no problem. The `with` keyword just provides a little more protection - it makes sure the file is closed. You could also just do open/close as I did within the `with`.